# stringify match result

Tags: javascript, regex

How to show all matches content like for example

```
     [
      'JavaScript',
      index: 14,
      input: 'I am learning JavaScript not Java.',
      groups: undefined
    ]
    [
      'Java',
      index: 29,
      input: 'I am learning JavaScript not Java.',
      groups: undefined
    ]
```

JSON.stringify doesn't seem to work : https://jsfiddle.net/spxh6ev0/

```
    const string = "I am learning JavaScript not Java.";
    const re = /Java[a-z]*/gi;

    let result = string.matchAll(re);

    for (let match of result) {
      alert(JSON.stringify(match));
    }
```

Comment: JSON just doesn't serialize non-array-index array properties. E.g. `const a = []; a.someprop = 0; JSON.stringify(a) === '[]';`. Also while your desired result may count as chrome console output, it's not valid javascript, and also not valid JSON, so your desired result is a bit unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to represent an associative array in JSON. So, it removes all those properties from the array.

If you spread the associative array within `{}`, it will create an object with all those enumerable properties. This will still remove `groups` if you `stringify` because `undefined` isn't a valid value in JSON

```js
const string = "I am learning JavaScript not Java.",
      re = /Java[a-z]*/gi,
      result = string.matchAll(re);

for (let match of result) {
  console.log({ ...match });
}
```

Shorter version:

```
const output = Array.from(result, match => ({ ...match }) )
```

Answer (score 4):

[`String#prototype#matchAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll) returns an iterable, you need to typecast it to an array and reshape it to match your output like this -

```js
const string = "I am learning JavaScript not Java.";
const re = /Java[a-z]*/gi;

let result = [...string.matchAll(re)].map((x) => ({
  match: x[0],
  index: x.index,
  input: x.input,
  groups: x.groups
}));

for (let match of result) {
  console.log(match);
}
```