# Is it possible to see inside Iterator contents with Chrome dev tools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

Instead of [stringify match result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67707566/stringify-match-result) of doing by code

```js
const string = "I am learning JavaScript not Java.",
  re = /Java[a-z]*/gi,
  result = string.matchAll(re);

for (let match of result) {
  console.log({ ...match });
}
```

I tried but I can't see any values:

[image]

Comment: What's wrong with what you're doing? It shows the match contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in chrome dev tool console

```
[...result];
```